# Wine throwing errors since going to 13.10

Tags: wine, 13.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10, running any program in Wine produces the following errors (via CLI):

```
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000000 at address (nil) (thread 000f), starting debugger...
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000000 at address (nil) (thread 0014), starting debugger...
wine client error:14: write: Bad file descriptor
err:wineboot:start_services_process Unexpected termination of services.exe - exit code -1073741819
```

(These also generate two popup windows saying that an undefined application has crashed).

After this, the program I was trying to run in the first place executes as normal. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the removal of ia32-libs, as the system version of wine is x64 ... I also have PlayOnLinux for managing several 32-bit wine prefixes and those still run fine.

Comment: I just tried re-adding ia32-libs from raring sources for kicks and it had no effect.

Comment: similar error: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181520

Comment: I have the same problem with wine 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was fixed about a week after the release of 13.10 -- looks like Canonical caught the issue and delivered a new package.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `sudo apt-get purge wine; sudo apt-get install wine` however I would recommend using `playonlinux` instead of wine directly; it's easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Issue described in question was fixed in updated version of wine package. There is no need to follow my answer anymore.

This problem only occurs with 64-bit version of wine.

To fix it, remove wine folder:

`rm -rf ~/.wine`

Then execute following command:

`WINEARCH=win32 wineboot --update`

Now you can install any application and it should work just fine.

Answer was taken from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181520

Comment: this isn't really an acceptable answer to me -- I have a lot of things already configured in that wine prefix. 64-bit wine shouldn't just break on upgrade.

Comment: @Rafal: Does this mean that all applications will run in 32bit instead of 64bit? I would much prefer 64bit.

Comment: @donquixote I am not sure. However, this issue was quickly fixed in wine, so my answer is no longer needeed. Just update wine package and all should be fine.